# How to run firefox browsers tests for a single test file in playwright in parallel

Tags: node.js, playwright

I have one single test file

If I run npx playwright test --headed --project=firefox --workers 1

this means that playwright will run a test of my file containing test operations with a single firefox browser.

Now, still with only 1 test file, I want to run 3 tests in parallel with 3 firefox browsers, with each firefox browser executing my test file.

Do you have any idea how I can do this?

Thanks a lot for your help

Comment: Running in node, python, dotnet or java? In Node, you can do this:  https://playwright.dev/docs/api/class-testconfig#test-config-fully-parallel

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

#### Parallelize tests in a single file

By default, tests in a single file are run in order. If you have many independent tests in a single file, you might want to run them in parallel with test.describe.configure().

```
import { test } from '@playwright/test';

test.describe.configure({ mode: 'parallel' });

test('runs in parallel 1', async ({ page }) => { /* ... */ });
test('runs in parallel 2', async ({ page }) => { /* ... */ });
```

> **Note**: Parallel tests are executed in separate worker processes and
> cannot share any state or global variables. Each test executes all
> relevant hooks just for itself, including beforeAll and afterAll.

Reference:https://playwright.dev/docs/test-parallel#parallelize-tests-in-a-single-file